# To where do `IDBOpenDBRequest` "error" events bubble up?

Tags: indexeddb

What is the significance of the `"error"`-type events dispatched on an `IDBOpenDBRequest` (i.e., [`open`](http://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#dom-idbfactory-open) and [`deleteDatabase`](http://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#dom-idbfactory-deletedatabase)) being described as bubbling? Should they bubble to `window` or do they not really go anywhere?*

(And for a bonus question, do "error" events on the non-standard `webkitGetDatabaseNames` similarly "bubble", and if so, where?)

* [The spec](http://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#dom-idbfactory-open) states:

> The firing of "success" or "error" events do not follow the normal
>   steps to fire a success event or fire an error event as there is no
>   active transaction at the time when they fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a spec issue:

https://github.com/w3c/IndexedDB/issues/86

It appears to be a "copy/paste" bug in the spec, but when window.onerror (and the corresponding global error hook in workers, etc) is integrated it will matter there. Firefox already implements.

Chrome is the only browser that implements the nonstandard `webkitGetDatabaseNames` and does not implement global onerror reporting yet, so they don't go anywhere.

Comment: So you mean it shouldn't be described in the spec as such currently, but in any case, when `window.onerror`, etc. are added to the spec, it should (continue to) indicate there is bubbling? And I assume other bubbling events will go up to `window.error` as well? And 3rd related question: the only other path for bubbling in the spec is `(((IDBRequest->)IDBTransaction->)IDBDatabase->)window.error (once available and only for errors)`?

Comment: Sorry, now that Github is back online, I see that the answers to my questions should be: 1. Yes 2. Yes. 3. Yes (besides workers)